# in run for event in pygame.event.get(): pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python

I get the Error("in run for event in pygame.event.get():pygame.error: video system not initialized"). Why? Can anyone help and explain?

```
import pygame
import sys


class Game:
    def __int__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            dt = self.clock.tick() / 1000
            pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the following typo:

```
def __int__(self):
```

should be

```
def __init__(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, Pygame has not been initialised. It has not been initialised, because the init() function was not called. You misspelled init() as int() so the function wasn’t called. You need to change that from:

```
def __int__(self):
    pygame.init()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

To:

```
#Change to init
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```